# How do I get purchased and ripped music from my iPhone to iTunes when it won't sync the traditional ways

Tags: iphone, itunes, windows, music

Okay, so I have a BUNCH of music on my old iPhone and my best friend wants to convince her mom to let her have it.  First, I want the music off it, because they're my favorite artist.  Also randomly I got a bunch of other songs my mom downloaded for me, and I really want those too.

Here's my issue.  Most of the songs were either on the phone before I got, or I ripped some CDs.  Now I've done this before, but with when I went to sync my music.  It said 0 songs.  I have over two hundred songs. I'd like to add that when you go to your music, or at least when I did before my last computer crashed that had all my music from iTunes, plus over 600 more, it pulls up all your music to sync.

When I tried to back up my phone to hopefully get it that way, it made me authorize my computer almost three times to transfer my purchases then it told me I just authorized three out of the five computers when we only have two in our house!

It didn't sync my purchases from the backup either.  Another thing, the only thing that it synced was the voice memos from my recordings.  -_-

If you guys have any alternatives or if I'm just out of luck.  Because the CDs have miraculously disappeared.  Things do that in my room.  Like my package of bookmarks.  Or my double disk of Grease 1&2. Anyway.  It'd be great if you could help me.

Answer (score 1):

This can definitely be done, one of two ways.

Free way and non-free way

**FREE WAY**

1. Download [MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/), free version
2. Install and in preferences or settings modify (if needed) where you want things to be sync'd (from phone to pc).
3. Plug your phone in, sync.  It's not made by Apple so it'll pull every song off your phone and onto your harddrive
4. May need to move songs from the MediaMonkey location to iTunes location
5. May need to deal with some dupes

**NON-FREE WAY**

1. Read this article [how-to-copy-music-from-your-iphone-ipad-or-ipod-touch-to-your-computer-for-free](http://lifehacker.com/5869827/how-to-copy-music-from-your-iphone-ipad-or-ipod-touch-to-your-computer-for-free)
2. Buy referenced software and follow their instrux.  Likely very similar to above steps

If you're going the buy route, check out this company as they make good stuff [Macroplant iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/)

Finally if you're on a Mac you'll need to substitute Doubletwist for MediaMonkey

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
1st download all your ,purchased music directly into your iPhone by going to the iTunes store, more, purchases click on what you want to download. (this may take some time)
Do not plug phone into computer yet.
Do not select entire music, select by artist, album, genre playlist.
Disconnect you iPhone from WiFI and put it in Airplane mode.
Click Sync.
Took me hours to figure this out after reading so many post on Red Circles and Gray dotted circles etc and ripped music not loading hope this helps